# - (void)dealloc Question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-management

Can you tell me if the following code is 100% correct? Expecially the `dealloc` section

***FirstViewController.h***

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@class SecondViewController

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController
{
    SecondViewController   *SecondController;
}

- (IBAction)SwitchView;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet SecondViewController *SecondController;

@end
```

***FirstViewController.m***

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@implementation FirstViewController

@synthesize SecondController;

- (IBAction)SwitchView
{    
    SecondController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    SecondController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
    [self presentModalViewController:SecondController animated:YES];
    [SecondController release];
}

/// OTHER CODE HERE ///

- (void)dealloc
{
    [SecondController release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Thanks!

Comment: One question, who is responsible for dismissing the SecondController instance?

Comment: You really *really* don't want to call your instance variable **SecondController**.  Call it `secondController`.  I'm surprised the compiler even compiles that code.

Comment: @bbum why on earth would a compiler check variable case and/or spelling?!

Comment: I read `SecondController` and `SecondViewController` as the same thing;  my mistake.  But also indicative of why instance variables should always start with a lower case letter.   The static analyzer *should* flag this.

Comment: @mvds: I think @bbum is getting at the convention that instance variables are typically lowercase to easily distinguish them from class identifiers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No it is not correct. You are sending the `release` message to a pointer in `dealloc`, but the pointer may or may not point to the SecondController anymore. This may lead to some very weird bugs, typically random objects being released.

In objective-c terms, your class doesn't retain (think "own") the SecondController, so it should not try to release it in the first place on `dealloc`.

To claim and release ownership the correct way, make it so:

```
- (IBAction)SwitchView
{    
    self.SecondController = [[[SecondViewController alloc] 
                  initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    self.SecondController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
    [self presentModalViewController:self.SecondController animated:YES];
}

/// OTHER CODE HERE ///

- (void)dealloc
{
    self.SecondController = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
```

This will also protect you from any other stuff happening between `SwitchView` and `dealloc`. (as long as that stuff follows the rules and uses `self.SecondController = ...` to change the property)

In `SwitchView` the `alloc`/`autorelease` sequence makes that your routine keeps ownership for the length of the routine (and a little beyond). The `self.SecondController =` part makes sure that your class retains the `SecondController` object, since you declared it `(nonatomic,retain)`.

Answer (score 4):

You should use the property setter to assign `SecondController`.

I suggest you only `alloc/init` that view controller once, then in `SwitchView` show it:

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@implementation FirstViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundle {
   if((self = [super initWithNibName:nibName bundle:nibBundle])) {
      self.SecondController = [[[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
      SecondController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
   }
   return self;
}

- (IBAction)SwitchView
{    
    [self presentModalViewController:SecondController animated:YES];
}

/// OTHER CODE HERE ///

- (void)dealloc
{
    [SecondController release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

This way, you only actually create that `SecondController` view controller once, as opposed to creating it every time `-SwitchView` is invoked.

Comment: Note that you don't necessarily want the secondviewcontroller instantiated when this controller loads: if you do this a lot, app startup will become slow. And if you go down this path, maybe also consider initializing everything from a nib (yes, that is both the First and the SecondViewController - just add a UIViewController to the FirstViewController nib and change the Class name to SecondViewController)